# Multiline Find & Replace in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ide, replace, multiline

Can it be done? We're using [VS2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2005), [VS2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2008), and [VS2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2010).

I don't mean regular expressions—which have their place—but plain old text find and replace. I know we can do it (at a pinch) with regular expressions using the *\n* tag, but we prefer not to get tangled up in regex escape characters, plus there's a readability issue.

If it can't be done, what plain and simple (free) alternative are people using? That doesn't involve knocking up our own macro.

Comment: If you're at the point of considering extra software/writing a macro to do it I'd say just bite the bullet and learn how to use the regex find/replace. At least it's built in and has decent help...

Comment: i know how to do regex but any text with a lot of punctuation in it is going to need an awful lot of regex fine tuning. i can't believe that's anyone's cup of tea for a simple find/replace operation

Comment: Vote [this MSConnect feature request](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/661437/multiline-find-replace-functionality) to try to get a built-in solution for this.

Comment: Any update on this question? From its comments it doesn't seem like the top answer completely works. It'd be great if there were a good solution for this...

Comment: Related meta question: *[Are questions specific to Excel VBA's IDE considered on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420699/)*. In particular, [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420699/are-questions-specific-to-excel-vbas-ide-considered-on-topic/420701#420701) references this one.

Comment: Macro support was [allegedly dropped starting with Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013-2015-2017-2019).

Answer (score 67):

I finally found it...

There isn't any need to download and load any external macro.

It’s working in Visual Studio 2008 with in-built macro at least. :)

Steps:

1. Select text you want to find.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> or open "Tools -> Macros -> Macro Explorer"
3. Double click *Sample* → *Utilities* → *FindLine*. (It will open the *Find* box with your selection loaded in the "Find" field. Don't worry about truncated text shown in the "Find" field. Trust me, the field has it all... The Microsoft way of showing it may be... :) )
4. Click on the "Quick Replace" button in the "Find And Replace" dialog box. Enter your replace with text.
5. And *click* any of three buttons as per your requirement...and it’s done. :)

Hurray... it’s working. It may not be a straightforward way to do it, but you know with Microsoft. Nothing is straightforward and easy.. :)

Comment: This doesn't handle "find in files" right?  Near as I can tell, it's single-file only?

Comment: @tlianza In VS2010, you can change the Quick Find dialog into Find in Files or Replace in Files using the buttons near the top of the screen. So, once the macro has populated the quick find dialog, you can switch to another view.

Comment: I don't think this works if your replacement text also spans multiple lines. When you paste into the "Replace With" box, it gets truncated.

Comment: Just have to link a keyboard shortcut to this macros and it will be simple like a common find and replace. Thank you very for this trick!

Comment: @Kos I think you have to change Look in dropdown value to Current Document

Comment: It doesn't work when your regex search must match across multiple lines. Voted down for that.

Comment: Looks like multi-line find to me.

Comment: Macros have been retired in following Visual Studio versions so this no longer works.

Comment: Macro support was [allegedly dropped starting with Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013-2015-2017-2019).

Answer (score 34):

This works today in Visual Studio 2012:

```
fooPatternToStart.*(.*\n)+?.*barPatternToEnd
```

See how the `(.*\n)+?` part does the match across multiple lines, non-greedy.
`fooPatternToStart` is some regex pattern on your start line, while `barPatternToEnd` is your pattern to find on another line below, possibly many lines below...

Example found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2010/05/29/140147.aspx).

Simple and effective :)

Note: **before** VS2012, the pattern that worked was: `fooPatternToStart.(.\n)+@.*barPatternToEnd`

Comment: Well explained and works exactly how it says on the box. Given that macros are long since dead even at the time of posting, I believe this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Macro support was [allegedly dropped starting with Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013-2015-2017-2019).

Answer (score 18):

You can search for multiline expressions by clicking on the "Use Regular Expressions" checkbox in the "Find and Replace" dialog. Line breaks are then indicated by `\n`.

[image]

Comment: How can we replace with a multi-line text? any ideas?

Comment: You may need to change `\n` to `\r\n` if your document has hidden carriage returns.

Comment: The question explicitly stated not using regular expressions. Regular expression has the draw back that not only you need to escape the line breaks you also need to escape all the match characters that would be regular expression escape characters. (vote down for not answer the question)

Answer (score 13):

I use this:
[Visual Studio Gallery Multiline Search and Replace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterMacej.MultilineSearchandReplace)

Comment: Can you elaborate in your answer?

Comment: [Slight elaboration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273434/multiline-find-replace-in-visual-studio/29276382#29276382), but not much.

Comment: Open VS 2022,  
Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> Online,  
Search : Multiline,  
Install : "Multiline Search and Replace" by Helixoft, 
New find tool added under:  Edit -> Find and Replace

Answer (score 3):

It’s provided by Microsoft only. Please check *[Multiline Search and Replace](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/699CE302-B0D4-4083-BE0E-1682E873CEBF)*.

It uses regular expression only. But for those who don't know regex, it is better to use it.

Comment: This was my solution, still applicable to this date.

Comment: The last paragraph *seems* contradictory. Can you [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29276382/edit)? (But ********** ***without*** ********** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 1):

You could also open the files with [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultraedit.html) which fully supports MultiLine replace. 
You can use the trial version if you only intend to use it once.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding [the comment of Andrew Corkery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273434/multiline-find-replace-in-visual-studio/2287762#comment8531435_2996626):

If you like to specify a multi-line replacement string as well, edit the macro code and set the replacement text as shown below.
This will allow you to "fine-tune" your replacement with just the small modifications needed.

```
Sub FindLine()
    Dim textSelection As TextSelection

    textSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    textSelection.CharLeft(True)
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Find")
    DTE.Find.FindWhat = textSelection.Text

    ' Also preset replacement text with current selection
    DTE.Find.ReplaceWith = textSelection.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: But the question said: *"That doesn't involve knocking up our own macro."*

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Comment: Macro support was [allegedly dropped starting with Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013-2015-2017-2019).

Answer (score 1):

The latest version (as of this posting) of [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) does multi-line find/replace. With no macro support in Visual Studio any more, this is relevant now.

Comment: Macro support was [allegedly dropped starting with Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013-2015-2017-2019).

Comment: Maze well use VsCode as you can open folders.

Answer (score 0):

this is deprecated and not supported any more according to  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/717692/is-the-macro-feature-removed-in-visual-studio-2022)