# How to replace multiple lines in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, editor

I need to do a find and replace, where I need to replace 2 lines at time.  Does anyone know how to do this in the VS2008 IDE?

To clarify, i want to replace 2 lines with 1 line.

Many thanks

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273434/multiline-find-replace-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to  [František Žiačik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123110/frantisek-ziacik) for the answer to this one.

To perform a find/replace, replacing multiple lines, you need to switch on regular expressions and use a line break (\n) between your lines, also using (:b*) at the start of each line to handle any tabs or spaces tabs.

So to find:

```
line one
line two
```

you would search for "**:b*line one\n:b*line two**"  (without the quotes)

Answer (score 3):

Try [Multiline Search and Replace macro](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/15?n=multiline-search-and-replace-in-visual-studio) for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the 'Use regular expressions' in the find dialog, and use `\n` to match a newline.
In your case, type `FirstLine\n:Zs*SecondLine`.

:Zs* skips leading blanks on line 2.

For example `,\n:Zs*c` matches a comma, newline, any number of blanks, a 'c'.

Comment: instead of :Zs you can use :b which matches tabs, too