# find multiple lines in Visual C++ 2008 Express Ed

Tags: c++, function, find, duplicates, lines

basically that's my question. Is it possible to find more than just one line in VS 2008? I would like to replace duplicate passages with a void function but sometimes there would be slight differences so it takes a lot of time to only find the same passages manually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question correctly, so can you give an example what do you want to replace?

As far as I understand you want to replace strings matching specific rules. Well for that you can use [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which is build into VS2008.

Comment: for example a couple of if clauses written in several lines: if(a=b){...}
if(c=d){...}
if(a=b){...} etc and those lines occur several times in the same order along the whole project. I want to replace those by a single function so that the compiler has less work and compiling doesn't take so long.

Comment: But the Find What option in VS2008 only allows to enter only one line at a time (copy/ pasting several lines won't work). So is there an option to find (& replace) several lines at a time

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273434/multiline-find-replace-in-visual-studio) should give an answer, there's also one written [macro](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/15) for doing that and you can modify it for your needs ;)

Comment: I've come across those links yesterday, too. However, there seems to be no Macro Explorer in my VS2008. Anyway, I've replaced the passages in question manually now. But Thx for help :-)